# Sharing data of template type between 2 template functions

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

Maybe I'm overestimating the metaprogramming capabilities of C++, but I expected to be able to create a class that acts as follows:

```
class Container
{
    template<class T> void Set(T* data)
    {
        //Store data somewhere
    }

    template<class T> T* Get()
    {
        //Return the data saved for T object
    }
};
```

Note: Templating Container itself is not an option.

If C++ allowed for template fields it would have been really simple, but instead I am resorting to an ugly technique that involves borgs, static variables in functions and passing `this` to distinguish between templated data for different instances of example.

I would really like a more elegant solution.

EDIT:
Here is an example of what i currently use(it is still a bit simplified version to make the point clearer)

Container.h

```
#include <functional>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
template<class T>
class FactoryContainer
{
public:
    function<T*()> GetFactoryForContainerInstance(void* container)
    {
        return FactoryContainer<T>::factories[container];
    };

    void SetFactoryForContainerInstance(void* container, function<T*()> factory)
    {
        FactoryContainer<T>::factories[container] = factory;
    };

private:
    static map<void*, function<T*()> > factories;
};

template<class T>
map<void*, function<T*()> > FactoryContainer<T>::factories = map<void*, function<T*()>> ();

class Container
{
public:
    template<class T> void Register(function<T*()> factory)
    {
        SetFactory<T>(factory);
    };
    template<class T> T* Resolve()
    {
        return GetFactory<T>()();
    };

private:
    template<class T>
    function<T*()> GetFactory()
    {
        return FactoryContainer<T>().GetFactoryForContainerInstance(this);
    };

    template<class T>
    void  SetFactory(function<T*()> factory)
    {
        FactoryContainer<T>().SetFactoryForContainerInstance(this, factory);
    };
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include "Container.h"
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    std::cout << "And thus it has began" << std::endl;

    Container c;
    function<int*()> foo = [] () { return new int(1);};
    c.Register<int>(foo);
    int* i = c.Resolve<int>();
    std::cout << *i  << std::endl; // prints 1
    delete i;
    function<string*()> foo2 = [] () { return new string("I hope it is clear now!");};
    c.Register<string>(foo2);
    string* s = c.Resolve<string>();
    std::cout << *c.Resolve<string>() << std::endl; // prints I hope it is clear now!
    delete s;
    Container c2;
    try
    {
        string* s2 = c2.Resolve<string>();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "Exception caught, yay!" << std::endl; // exception is intended as there was no registrations on c2,
                                                            //that is why passing void* is needed in implementation
    }

}
```

What i would like to be able to do is to avoid using `FactoryContainer` borg.

That is my first question on SO, so please cut me some slack.
Thank you!

Comment: Why is templating the container not an option? That's the canonical way in C++.

Comment: Because the question is about storing different typed data in one class, instead of having as many classes as many different T exist. This Container class is just an simple example to illustrate what i want to do

Comment: Seems you need boost::any or if your space of variation is less than everything then boost::variant<type1,type2,etc>

Comment: It may be helpful if you add your current "inelegant" solution (borgs, etc.) so it's possible to see exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @mfitzp Yes, i am working on it, obviosly i wasn't very clear in the question

Comment: Please post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that describes what you want to happen.  Demonstrate how you want your class to be used, what results you want, and what results you get with your current non-working attempt.

Comment: @Goldseeker _"Woking on it!"_ Do that prior asking next time please!

Comment: @Yakk  Edited question, it should be much clearer now

Comment: The top question is about storing and retrieving a `T*`, but then all the later code stores a `std::function<T*()>` and retrieves a `T*`.  Which is it that you want?

Comment: @Mooing Duck there is little to none difference, solution for the first one will be pretty much the same as the solution for the second one

Comment: @JonathanWakely borg pattern or monostate pattern, is a singletone-like pattern. With singletone you can construct only one instance of an object, and with borg you can have as many instances as you want, but all borg instances work with the same static data.

Comment: OK, that's Monostate ... I haven't come across the alternative name, and don't think it's a good idea to use two different names for the same pattern, it defeats the point of using a common  vocabulary to talk about the pattern.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I came to know it as borg, so i used that name. Actually google gives ~2500 results for "borg pattern" query and ~1400 result for "monostate pattern", so, arguably, borg is even more  commonly used than monostate. Anyway, that is offtopic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are a few parts.  First, looking up runtime data based off a type.  `std::type_index` solves this problem for you together with `typeid` operator.

The second part is storing data of an unknown type.  `std::experimental::any` does this.

The third part would be to wrap it up so you don't have to think about it.

```
struct poly_storage {
  std::unordered_map< std::type_index, std::experimental::any > data;
  template<class T, class...Args> void store( Args&&... args ) {
    auto it = data.find(typeid(T));
    if (it == data.end()) {
      data.emplace(
        std::make_pair( typeid(T), T{std::forward<Args>(args)...} )
      );
    } else {
      data[typeid(T)] = T{ std::forward<Args>(args)... };
    }
  }
  template<class T>
  T* get() {
    auto it = data.find(typeid(T));
    if (it == data.end()) return nullptr;
    return std::any_cast<T>(&(it->second));
  }
  template<class T>
  T const* get() const {
    auto it = data.find(typeid(T));
    if (it == data.end()) return nullptr;
    return std::any_cast<T>(&(it->second));
  }
};
```

`poly_storage.store<T>( blah )` stores `blah` under the key of `T` as a `T`.

`poly_storage.get<T>()` returns a `T*` that is `nullptr` if the get failed.  It also supports `const` access.

`any` is basically a type-safe `void*`.

Comment: I have considered solution with typeid(not as fancy as yours, but the idea was the same), but it really bums me out to use RTTI when the data is clearly known in compile-time(with simple code generation i could have created a list of all the types used with Get or Set and used solution akin to the one Jaron42 proposed). I will continue to look for better solution. Anyway, thank you for trying to help.

Comment: @Goldseeker I think I see your problem.  You think that the compiler knows what types are used for a given instance at compile time.  The compiler only sees what happens within a given translation unit (cpp file), while objects of a given type can live in more than one.  In one translation unit stores an `int`, that data cannot be communicated to other translation units.  The `sizeof` an instance of `Container` cannot be a function of how it or its members are used.  So `Container` needs to either dynamically grow (see above `typeindex` solution), or the data cannot be stored there.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you! That is exactly what my problem was. How i could have missed that. Now i know for sure that it cannot be done as i imagined and can move one to runtime solutions. I will mark you answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to R.Sahu's answer but using `std::tuple` (requires C++14, but can be done in C++11)

```
template<typename ... Args>
class Container
{
public:
    template<class T> void Set(const T& value)
    {
        std::get<T>(data) = value;
    }

    template<class T> const T& Get() const
    {
       return std::get<T>(data);
    }

private:
    std::tuple<Args...> data;
};

int main()
{
   Container<int, float, double> c;
   c.Set(10);
   c.Set(20.125f);
   c.Set(30.7890);

   std::cout << c.Get<int>() << std::endl;
   std::cout << c.Get<float>() << std::endl;
   std::cout << c.Get<double>() << std::endl;
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2397a48598d5b300)

Comment: I actually like this approach, but in my situation there will be much more types in Args, so it will be very inconvenient for the user to specify so many types when creating Container.

Comment: @Goldseeker: sounds like you just want to use `boost::any` _instead_ of `Container`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to be able to call `c.Get()` and have it return whatever was stored last, that's not possible.

> Maybe i'm overestimating metaprogramming capabilities of C++

Not overestimating, you're confusing them for something they are not.

Templates (and the return type of functions) are static, compile-time properties. What you stored last in an object is a dynamic property.

The return type of `Get` must be known at compile-time, which would require the compiler to statically-analyze the rest of the program to determine what the last call to `Set` was and what type it stored. That's not possible in the general case, the call to `Set` might be in a different translation unit not visible to the compiler, or you could do:

```
Container c;
int i = 1;
std::string s = "two";
if (rand() % 2)
  c.Set(&i);
else
  c.Set(&s);
auto res = c.Get();  // What is the type here?
```

If making the container a template is not an option you'll need to write the code yourself to dynamically store any type (look into "type erasure") and then either

- have `Get` return something "un-typed" like `void*` or `std::experimental::any` or `boost::any` and require the user to cast back to the original type; or
- require the user to call `Get<int>()` so they specify the type and have the container do the casting.

For example, using `std::experimental::any` to perform the type erasure and casting looks like this:

```
class Container
{
    std::experimental::any m_data;

public:
    template<class T> void Set(T* data)
    {
        m_data = std::experimental::any(data);
    }

    template<class T> T* Get()
    {
        return std::experimental::any_cast<T*>(m_data)
    }
};

Container c;
int i = 1;
c.Set(&i);
int* pi = c.Get<int>();
std::string s = "two";
c.Set(&s);
std::string* ps = c.Get<std::string*>();
// this will return a null pointer:
pi = c.Get<int*>();
```

(N.B. this doesn't really give you any advantage over using `any` directly, but maybe you want to add other functionality so the `Container` type would make sense.)

Comment: Obviosly i intend for user to specify type for Get, and i do not what the behavior where Get returns last item set, what i want to to is for Get<int> return data that was set with last Set<int> call

Comment: @Goldseeker no, that was not obvious.

Comment: No, it wasn't obvious. Maybe if you'd included the example in your original question, instead of some vague references to "borgs" it would have been clearer. Anyway, my answer still applies: use `any`

Comment: @JonathanWakely, you misunderstood my question. I know how to accomplish what i want using `void*`, `any` and/or RTTI, what i wanted is a solution that somehow uses templates to do it during compile-time, @Yakk explained to me why it is not possible in his answer

Comment: As I said above, "Templates (and the return type of functions) are static, compile-time properties. What you stored last in an object is a dynamic property." That's still true if you remove the word "last". And "the call to Set might be in a different translation unit not visible to the compiler". Apparently you misunderstood my answer too, because it was still relevant  :)

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you are looking for but hopefully the following code gives you some ideas.

```
#include <iostream>

class Container
{
   public:

    template<class T> void Set(T data)
    {
       static_cast<Datum<T>&>(data_).datum = data;
    }

    template<class T> T Get() const
    {
       return static_cast<Datum<T> const&>(data_).datum;
    }

   private:

    template <typename T>
    struct Datum
    {
       T datum;
    };

    struct Data : Datum<int>,
                  Datum<float>,
                  Datum<double>
   {
   };

    Data data_;
};

int main()
{
   Container c;
   c.Set(10);
   c.Set(20.125f);
   c.Set(30.7890);

   std::cout << c.Get<int>() << std::endl;
   std::cout << c.Get<float>() << std::endl;
   std::cout << c.Get<double>() << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually that is very close to what i want to do, but obviosly  i need to automagically compose the list of types for data to derive from

Comment: You may use `std::tuple` and `std::get<T>` instead of `Data`.